# C# 3.5 - Connecting named pipe across network

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, networking, named-pipes

What is the correct way to setup a named pipe in C# across a network?

Currently I have two machines, 'client' and 'server'.

Server sets up its pipe in the following manner:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    "pipe",
    PipeDirection.InOut,
    10,
    PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
    PipeOptions.None)
pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
//... Read some data from the pipe
```

The client sets up its connection in the following manner:

```
NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(
    "server",
    "pipe",
    PipeDirection.InOut);
pipeClient.Connect(); //This line throws an exception
//... Write some data to the pipe
```

The 'server' machine can be accessed on the network by going to "\\server".

Whenever I run the program, I get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException that says "Access to the path is denied." The code works fine when I run the server and client on my local machine and attempt to connect to "." with the client.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It is not possible to used named pipes between machines.

"The WCF-NetNamedPipe adapter provides cross-process communication on the **same computer**"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226493.aspx

Comment: This is Bizz Server, not Windows doc.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx states that it should work!

Comment: That may be a WCF limitation. Named pipes in Windows (like the one the person is asking about) can work across networks. 

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx

"Named pipes can be used for interprocess communication locally or over a network"  

There are some limitations  
 - Local lans only (so the moment you hit a router it stops)  
 - Older versions of Windows (like 2000) limit to 10 connections  
 - Anonymous pipes are single machine only

Answer (score 4):

You need to set permissions on the NamedPipeServerStream so that the client will have permissions to access the pipe.

I would look at the SetAccessControl method of your NamedPipeServerStream.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the System.Runtime.Remoting namespace.  IIRC, named pipes are one option for the protocol used by remoting channels.