# Communication between apps in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application suite I'm coding at work that consists of multiple programs each designed to handle a specific task.  For example, one app lets you search your list of customers and make a reservation for that customer to check out equipment.  Another app lets you look up that reservation that was already made, and proceed straight to check out where we record what equipment they took, etc.

I'm also designing a notification system to go along with this suite. (if you've used Groupwise email, picture it like the email notifications.  Or even the reminders on Google calendar).  I'd like to have the user only need to log into one main application which is also the notification app.  Then every other app they opened in the suite would check some system variable/.NET object or whatever, and see that they're already logged in and not require them to do so again.  Btw, this "login" is actually to log into MySQL, which is our database of reservations, checkouts, inventory state, dept customers, etc.

My question is: What's the best way to do something like this?  Would it be by having each app search the .NET runtime for the main app and check to see that its currently logged in or something?  I've never done anything like this before.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why this wouldn't be a web application? It'd be distributed,  accessible from various devices, all forms could be implemented separately, the login would be tracked as a session, etc. Sounds like a good candidate instead of solving problems that come with breaking it up into a bunch of .exe-s.

Comment: Look here, especially the answer mentioning WCF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284124/communication-between-programs-in-net?rq=1

Comment: So I think the question here is, are you open to leveraging Windows Authentication?

Comment: Also, I would consider using MySQL as a way to make the program aware of each other, in some way or another. For example, if the "login" is a log into MySQL for all applications, as you say, then each one can first check if a user is already logged in by looking into the relevant sql table instead of searching for running applications...

Comment: I would consider this to be a poor design. I've seen systems designed like this before and they are usually like a stack of cards that all come crashing down when something goes wrong.

Comment: Totally agree with @TimB. Why would you do N applications that all refer to the same stuff/business process and will be used by the same users?... It's not a good idea from ANY point of view.. this is, not from UX, development, deployment, maintenance, scalability point of views.

Comment: You could maybe use some resource using Mutexes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1.aspx I've never used it myself, but it talks about marshaling resources across application domain boundaries, so perhaps look into that?

Comment: Named semaphores might provide a way for each application to have some knowledge of the other apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Comment: As far as why it wouldn't be a web app?  Ehhhh, mostly just because I don't know much about them.  I'm kinda old school :p.  Our environment here is Apache, and the development space that I previously used to test my .php code no longer runs php, just html.  In order to get access to the real server where I can test my php code, I think it'd take an act of Congress sometimes.  So I started over a month ago with the freebie VS 2012 Express.  I actually had a fair portion of this done in php but I wasn't satisfied with it.  Then the server I used lost php support.

Comment: What is a server if does not support PHP or ASP.NET? It is simple to make any server support ASP.NET and/or PHP. I would take the time to make this a web application. If the servers are not accessible and you cannot work through the bureaucratic issues push to the cloud via Azure, App Harbor, Heroku or the likes. Since you are old school and you are not satisfied with your PHP attempt you can use web forms and be up running with one web app that handles all authentication quickly.

Comment: I work for a university's IT department for the record.  I'm kindof the "bastard stepchild" in that I actually run the Audiovisual Services division of IT.  I'm more of a programming hobbyist.  I've approached our web developer about making this thing into a web app, but if you've ever worked for a university you know it can take ages to get anyone to commit to something fully.  And as far as making it a web app myself... well I just really don't have that skillset.  I'd have to start from scratch to learn it.  I've been doing Java for a while though and the transition to C# has been nice.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use multiple processes in order to have separation of state, so that failure in one doesn't take down the whole bunch.  You seem to want the opposite, however.

So, use one main application process.  Whenever another applet is clicked (be it from Start Menu, desktop shortcut, etc), it forwards its command-line to the main application and closes.  The singular process receives the new launch request and opens the corresponding window.

Win32 has mailslot objects for this sort of thing, but I'm sure you can find a more .NET-purist approach using WCF or similar.