# WCF named pipes: Across network? Really?

Tags: .net, wcf, named-pipes

Many people seem to [think this it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244367/c-3-5-connecting-named-pipe-across-network), yet clearly in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226493%28BTS.10%29.aspx) the boundary is stated as inter-process which to my mind means "no network".

[Another document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) is completely unambiguous:

> The named pipe transport has very little reach; it can only connect to services running on the same machine

So why are so many posters here saying it can work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to make a distinction between **Named Pipe** and WCF binding implementation **NETNamedPipeBinding**.

The NetNamedPipeBinding is a predefined binding for WCF for on-machine communication.

> Provides a secure and reliable binding that is optimized for on-machine communication.

But if you check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx) about Named Pipes, you can see that it is possible to setup a named pipe across network.

> Named pipes can be used to provide communication between processes on the same computer or between processes on different computers across a network

Comment: So why does WCF exclude inter-machine comms on their named-pipes?

Comment: @spender: No idea. You would need to ask Microsoft for the answer.

Comment: Because named pipes works over TCP/IP when remoted.  In which case, you might as well use the NetTcpBinding.

Answer (score 6):

In general, named pipes work across the network. However, using named pipes with WCF, you're restricted to on-machine communications. That's why your first and last links are both correct.